# O365: Setting up OneDrive for Business on behalf of users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

I have a Tenant in O365 with a large number of users. A PowerShell script I have enables OneDrive for Business for batches of these at which point we want to be able to import files into their drive.

Trouble is, OneDrive isn’t usually available until the user has manually logged into the portal and clicked on the OneDrive tile at which point are shown a message along the lines of “Hang-on while we set up your OneDrive”.

Is there any way to automate this process rather than having the manual touch for each user?

Answer (score 0):

I think I’ve found the solution as it goes, just couldn’t think of the term for doing this at the time of composing - [How to pre-provision user sites in OneDrive for Business](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/How-to-pre-provision-user-sites-in-OneDrive-for-Business-ceef6623-f54f-404d-8ee3-3ce1e338db07)

I’ll update with my findings.